# getting the html content of the url specified in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the $http.get('url') to get the content present in the 'url' present. The html in 'url' is as follows

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <pre style = "word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
        <!-- content is present here -->
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

When I make a $http.get to this url, I get some data and the required content

```
GET /TYPE=abvd HTTP 1.1
content required

.0.1234.123 Safari /123.12
Referer: //url of the webpage calling this function
Accept-Encoding: 
...............
```

How do I get rid of this extra information and receive only the content? (I know we can just parse the response but is there a better way of doing it? )

EDIT:
The data response I got was seen in google chrome, when I run the same script in IE10, I get the only the "html content" as desired. Why does this difference occur and how do I make process it?

Comment: those are response headers which will come with all http requests... you can modify your server response to change them... but they are harmless and you really don't have to worry about them

Comment: i might not be able to modify the server response.

Answer (score 3):

`$http.get` returns an [HttpPromise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get), and from it you can get the underlying data like so:

```
$http.get('url').then(function(response) {
    html = response.data;
});
```

To get even more useful data, you can expand this like so:

```
$http.get('url').then(
   // success handler
   function(response) {
       var data = response.data,
           status = response.status,
           header = response.header,
           config = response.config;
   }, 
   // error handler
   function(response) {
       var data = response.data,
           status = response.status,
           header = response.header,
           config = response.config;
   });
```

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yozewu/1/embed?js,console,output)

**Edit:** If there are still HTML issues, you can look into `$sce.trustAsHtml(html)` or PhantomJS with references:

- [Parse an HTML document with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743142/parse-an-html-document-with-angularjs])
- [Scraping an AngularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026930/scraping-an-angularjs-application)

Comment: when i print response.data on the console, i get "undefined"

Comment: How about `console.log(response.status);`?

Comment: Demo with console.log outputs to screen: http://jsbin.com/memeva/1/embed?js,console,output

Comment: the url I am getting the data from is not in a json format, is it why this profblem is getting created?

Comment: Nope. This URL I'm using allows cross-origin requests specifically for demos. If the URL you use does not allow cross-origin requests and is on a different domain, then no data will be returned at all. Try my demo with your url and see what console outputs you get.

Comment: no, i meant, in content of the html that i am using is text format

Comment: To be sure, open the url in a browser and view the source. If there is header information present in the source, then it needs to be manually stripped. If the page source starts with `<html>`, then the above code should work barring and CORS issues.

Comment: page source starts with <html>, I have written the entire page source in the question.